# android vibrating only for 15 seconds

Tags: java, android, milliseconds

**I want to implement:**

I want to vibrate the phone for the specified minutes, I am getting the input using EditText and converting to millseconds by multiplying minutes with  60000 and then passing it as argument to vibrate(), it should vibrate for the specified millseconds, but its vibrating only for 15 seconds..

**I have done code:**

```
  Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
  final EditText minutess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minutes);
                // to string
                String min = minutess.getText().toString();
                minutess.setVisibility(4);
                stopButton.setVisibility(1);
                try{
                long mins = Long.parseLong(min);
                long milis = mins*60000;
                startButton.setVisibility(4);
                v.vibrate(milis);
                }
       catch (NumberFormatException e) 
            { 
               //something else done here

            }
```

Even when the time in milliseconds is passed to vibrate() , it vibrating only for 15 seconds only. 
I am very much new to java and I want to know if theres anything wrong in the above code ..

Comment: whats your problem exactly? do you want it to vibrate for 15 seconds only or anything else?

Comment: I want to vibrate the phone for the specified minutes, I am getting the input using EditText and converting to millseconds by multiplying minutes my 60000 and then passing it as argument to vibrate(), it should vibrate for the specified millseconds, but its vibrating only for 15 seconds..

Comment: I would do some additional debugging. It's quite possible another application (probably not yours) is stopping the vibrate. Also, does your application close after 15 seconds? If so, any vibrate commands it sends will stop as well.

Comment: what is `v` exactly in `v.vibrate(milis);?`

Comment: The application wont stop , I have also added android:keepScreenOn="true" as vibration stops when the screen goes off, but even though the screen is on, the vibration is stopped..

Comment: @PareshMayani: I have added it to the above code..

Comment: Let me know when your adult app is in the Play Store.

Comment: @StackOverflowed : haha, good one., but it was for something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't say [in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#vibrate%28long%29), but 15 seconds may be a hardware-set limit on vibration time. You may want to test it out on a different device to see if it goes longer or shorter before stopping.

But if all devices can only vibrate for 15 seconds, you could split the desired time into 15 seconds chunks, restarting the vibration each time until it should stop.